# Jenkins - /usr/bin/env: perl: No such file or directory

Tags: perl, jenkins, continuous-integration, karma-runner, vnc-server

I have strange problem - I wanted to use xvnc jenkins plugin because of karma tests for browsers like Chrome, Firefox etc...

But there is problem with running vncserver while building. Console output:

```
Starting xvnc
[workspace] $ vncserver :51 -localhost -nolisten tcp
/usr/bin/env: perl: No such file or directory
```

this is repeated several times and last output is

```
FATAL: Failed to run 'vncserver :61 -localhost -nolisten tcp' (exit code 127), blacklisting display #61; consider checking the "Clean up before start" option
```

I can understand the problem is that jenkins cannot find Perl but it is really weird because when I run `env perl` it works (even as a jenkins user).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: PATH not setup as desired when run from Jenkins?

Comment: @ikegami speaks wisdom.

Comment: Sorry for very late reply, I thought it can be PATH but when I execute env command in task I get this PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games which looks ok in my opinion, I can also run env perl without any problem

Answer (score 1):

For me this occurs when the [NodeJS](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) and [Xvnc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin) plugins are enabled during the same build.

I've reported this in [JENKINS-28578](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28578).